# MongoDB can't find existing documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the strangest issue. I have this piece of python code in which I use pymongo, and which runs as an automatic task with celery:

```
query_filter = {'current_data': {'$exists': True}}
record_list = [x['_id'] for x in db.records.find(query_filter, {'_id': 1})]
for i, record_id in enumerate(record_list):
    my_record = db.records.find_one({'_id': record_id})
    record_data = my_record['current_data']
    perform_action(record_data)
```

And it gives me this error:

```
record_data = my_record['current_data']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

`records` collection has 63500 documents, ~1% of them reach 80% of maximum size for MongoDB document (16 megabytes). I have pymongo version 3.4.0. Do you know what might be happening here?

Comment: Why do you use a list comprehension and `enumerate`? Why not just iterate over `x in db.records.find(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is very simple and straightforward: program runs long enough for people to delete records while I query them. Unprobable, but seems true.

Answer (score 0):

You query from the collection "records" first, then from the collection "record". Is that a typo? If so that's the cause of your bug: "find_one" in a non-existent collection returns None.